# Multiple alter scripts in flyway migrations not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I have created a flyway migration file with alter scripts for two different table.. But after migration applied successfully I can see the result for only one table.

Below is the script which I have added with file name V202001082022__add.sql

```
ALTER TABLE table1   
ADD COLUMN occupancytype character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
ADD COLUMN suboccupancytype character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
ADD COLUMN usages character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE table2  
ADD COLUMN occupancytype character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
ADD COLUMN suboccupancytype character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
ADD COLUMN usages character varying(64) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Here, table1 columns were added successfully but no columns were added in table2.

I want two scripts to be executed, Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: It's very strange because by default each migration script is executed within a transaction. It's either all or nothing.
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#transactions
May be you can find some flyway logs about migration execution.

Comment: yeah it is strange.. and I can see migration success message in my service logs and also in migration history table.